# Get return type OID of functions with node-postgres

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

When using `node-postgres` to query a Postgres database, a successful query returns the `pg.Result` type that has a `oid` property.

When querying a set returning function, `oid` is `null`.

Is there a way to get the `oid` of the return type when selecting from a function?

Answer (score 2):

The `Result.oid` property is not related to the return type.

Before Postgres 12, you could use `CREATE TABLE ... WITH OIDS` to include an automatically-assigned `oid` column in your table.

In the special case of a single-row `INSERT` into a table `WITH OIDS`, the server's [`CommandComplete` response](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/protocol-message-formats.html) contains the `oid` of the new row. For all other `INSERT`s, the `oid` is zero, and for all other commands, the response does not contain an `oid`.

The [`node-postgres` source](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/blob/566058de17ef0dd532c8005261c1750afa3984f1/lib/result.js#L45) shows that the `Result.oid` property is derived from this response. For a `SELECT` response, the `oid` is never assigned, so will be `null` regardless of what you're querying. The limited usefulness of this value (and of OID columns in general) probably explains why the `oid` property is [undocumented](https://node-postgres.com/api/result).

Return types are associated with *columns* of the result, not the result as a whole. You can get the type OID for a column using e.g.:

```
result.fields[0].dataTypeId
```